# How to start websocket graphql server

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql-js

I am trying to run the code from here https://the-guild.dev/blog/graphql-over-websockets. I put the server code with the code that is making the schema in a file called socket-server.js. Then I am just trying to use node src/socket-server.js. I get the `Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module:`

Clearly I am missing something obvious. I am new to using node and graphql and frontend programming as a whole. But how am I supposed to start the server mentioned in that blog article?

Comment: You should use graphql subscriptions.You can use this package [graphql-redis-subscriptions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-redis-subscriptions)

Comment: I was using old node. But thanks

Comment: I have used graphql websocket a year ago, but had to switch to the `ws` npm package.
Websocket from graphql was not enought for my requirements.

Comment: But isn't ws used in the code from the blog? Line 2 is `import ws from 'ws'; // yarn add ws`

Answer (score 0):

Ok I was just using an old version of node. Updating resolved the issue.